# Is there a tool or plugin to create a graphical representation of spring bean injections?

Tags: spring, dictionary, javabeans, code-injection

I've been asked as part of our project handover documentation to come up with a diagram/chart of our spring bean injection relationships. For reasons too long to go into here, we're not using auto wiring but have defined a large number of beans in an application context XML file.

Before I dust off my copy of Visio and slog my way through this task, is there a tool/eclipse plugin that can do this? Google searches have not turned anything up.

Comment: I used to use spring-beandoc for this; I haven't tried it since Spring 2.5, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has pretty good [support for Spring](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/), including automatic generation of diagrams based on XML:

[image: diagram]
<sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/screenshots/spring_diagrams.png))</sub>